# Preventing SQL injection

Tags: 6, database, security

In Drupal 6, queries are issued with `db_query()`. Using %-modifiers, query arguments are substituted into the query after being filtered. Strings %s (and only strings) are ultimately run through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (using [`db_escape_string()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysqli.inc/function/db_escape_string/6)).

Looking at the php docs for [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string), I see the following security warning:

> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function `mysqli_set_charset()` for it to affect `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

[The answer to another question about mysql_real_escape_string / SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703420/shortcomings-of-mysql-real-escape-string/12720360#12720360) explains that:

> Another way to get yourself into hot water using
> mysql_real_escape_string is when you set the database connection
> encoding using the wrong method. You should do this:
>
> `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);`
>
> You can also do this though:
>
> `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link);`
>
> The problem is that the latter
> bypasses the mysql_ API, which still thinks you're talking to the
> database using latin1 (or something else). [...] This can be used for
> injection attacks in certain multibyte string situations.

Drupal does not call mysqli_set_charset(), and instead issues the query 'SET NAMES utf8'. This can be seen in [db_connect()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysqli.inc/function/db_connect/6).

In order to properly protect Drupal 6 against SQL Injection, does the charset need to be set at the server level?

Answer (score 1):

This [answer to a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602) does a great job at explaining the attack that can get around mysqli_real_escape_string() using multi-byte character sets.

I've concluded that when running Drupal 6, we do **not** have to set the charset at the server level in order to be safe from the attack.

Drupal always sets the client to UTF8 (and not the GBK or BIG-5 charsets that are required for the exploit). Newer versions MySQL (> 5.1) are also not vulnerable.

HOWEVER, although Drupal is safe from this exploit, we should still follow the installation documentation which states, "The database should be created with UTF-8 (Unicode) encoding, for example utf8_general_ci.".

[One helpful comment](https://drupal.org/comment/6851624#comment-6851624) on the installation docs outlines *how* to create your database with UTF8 encoding, and how to ensure that UTF8 is used when performing a backup/restore:

> To achieve this by the mysql command line interface use the following commands:
>   `$ mysql -u root -p # Login`
>   `mysql> CREATE DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8; # Create with utf-8`
>
> When using mysqldump/mysql for backup/restore also force both server and client to utf8 by inserting into */etc/mysql/my.cnf*:
>   `default-character-set = utf8 # Server`
>   `skip-character-set-client-handshake # Force client`